# Domain & sub-domain server configuration for DNS & SSL fails with "certificate transparency required"

Tags: web-hosting, https, subdomain, nameserver

Here is the kind of configuration I would love to do:

[image]

I added an A record for my domain `example.com`. It is working at Host2 and now it is reachable. I bought an SSL certificate for `example.com` so that it works via HTTPS. It's working like a charm.

The problem is that I have an A record for `api.example.com` pointed to Host1 but I get `NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED` when I try to connect to that subdomain.

DNS configuration for HOST1:

[image]

I would love really to know why the `api.example.com` is not reachable, and whats wrong with my configuration.

Comment: What does the line from "example.com" to "Host1" represent?

Comment: Is your certificate a "wildcard" certificate that is meant to cover subdomains? Or alternately, did you add `api.example.com` do that certificate using SNI?

Comment: No, I bought an additional certificate for my sub-domain.

Comment: I mean that api.example.com is an app hosted from HOST1, and example.com hosted from HOST2. while both DNS configuration is on HOST1. for api.example i have the A record with api as name, and for example.com I have A record with @ name pointing to HOST2 ip address. but for example.com & api.example.com i have diffrente SSL.

Comment: Server architecture seems a bit outside of this site's scope.

Comment: This is not a DNS or IP error.

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Pro Webmasters. You may be able to get help on [sf]. As your question is currently written it *probably* would not meet that site's quality guidelines. I recommend reading their [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get is specific to some browsers, and its policies. It is not a feature of TLS or X.509 certificates. This error message is indeed specific to Google Chrome browser.

The company you used to generate the certificate should be able to help you (and give you a certificate working).

But in short, skip a lot of resources online about this error that **wrongly**  are saying you need to upgrade browsers (you need to do that in general, not in particular for this reaon), or cache problems, or corrupted certificate, or bad extensions, or incognito mode, or things like that.

The error message is a direct consequence of Google Chrome policies as you can read on this authoritative source on the subject: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/net/docs/certificate-transparency.md

Note in particular this two items (there is a third one specific to Symantec):

> Since 1 January 2015, Chrome has required that all Extended Validation certificates be disclosed via Certificate Transparency.

and

> For all new certificates issued after 30 April 2018, Chrome will require that the certificate be disclosed via Certificate Transparency. If a certificate is issued after this date and neither the certificate nor the site supports CT, then these certificates will be rejected as untrusted, and the connection will be blocked. In the case of a main page load, the user will see a full page certificate warning page, with the error code net::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED.

So, in short, all just means that the CA you used provided you with a certificate that they did not add to certificate transparency logs. This is a deficiency on their part and you should be able to get back to them to request  they provide you with a certificate that they did add to certificate transparency logs OR you will just need unfortunately to go somewhere else to buy such a certificate.

Or you don't use this specific browser but I haven't checked what others policies are. And if you have a public website you can't of course force your visitors to use a specific browser just because of a problem with a certificate.

Comment: When Google says the site could support ct, does that mean there's some configuration you could do on your end to enable it even if the certificate provider didn't do it for you?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The CA issuing the certificate has to include it in Certificate Transparency Logs. End-user can not do anything there. And once the certificate is issued, it is too late (because it is inside the certificate that there are details proving it has been included in various Certificate Logs)

Comment: In the above link, it is this part: "In general, a site operator does not need to take special action to support Certificate Transparency.  [..] Nearly every CA supports CT through the first method, meaning that when you get a certificate, it will already support CT and require no further configuration.". Outside of that, it is difficult to discuss more without even seeing what certificate we are talking about...

Comment: And even further in same document: "Supporting CT within the certificate itself is the preferred and recommended way to enable CT support. If you obtain a certificate from your CA and it does not support CT, then that generally indicates that your CA is not following industry best practice, and you should probably look for another CA to provide certificates for your sites."